# Rstudio - semPlot (lavaan) seems to output an unreadable plot no matter what (though factually correct)

Tags: r, analysis, semplot

I have a theoretical framework of 5 latent factors, each with 10 questions (big 5, personality questionaire). I want to create a semPlot of all 10*5 = 50 questions and 5 latent factors, and also visualize relationships between those. However, since there is a large amount of variables, the plot is unreadable and somehow very low quality, no matter what I do.

Here is my code (I created dummy DF):

```
df2 <- data.frame(O1 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  O2 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  O3 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  O4 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  O5 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  O6 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  O7 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  O8 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  O9 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  O10 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  C1 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  C2 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  C3 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  C4 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  C5 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  C6 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  C7 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  C8 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  C9 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  C10 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  E1 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  E2 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  E3 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  E4 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  E5 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  E6 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  E7 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  E8 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  E9 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  E10 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  A1 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  A2 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  A3 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  A4 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  A5 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  A6 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  A7 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  A8 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  A9 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  A10 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  N1 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  N2 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  N3 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  N4 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  N5 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  N6 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  N7 = seq(1,16,by=2),
                  N8 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  N9 = seq(1,16,by=2), 
                  N10 = seq(1,16,by=2))



model_fa <- ' Openness  =~ O1 + O2 +O3 + O4 + O5 + O6 + O7 + O8 + O9 + O10 
              Contientiousness =~ C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5 + C6 + C7 + C8 + C9 + C10
              Extraversion   =~ E1 + E2 + E3 + E4 + E5 + E6 + E7 + E8 + E9 + E10
              Agreeableness   =~ A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6 + A7 + A8 + A9 + A10
              Neuroticism   =~ N1 + N2 + N3 + N4 + N5 + N6 + N7 + N8 + N9 + N10'

#fit model - select just items
fit_cfa <- cfa(model_fa, data = df2, 
               std.lv=TRUE)

semPaths(fit_cfa, what = 'par', weighted = FALSE, layout = 'tree', nCharNodes = 1,
         residuals = F, thresholds = F, curvePivot=TRUE, rotation = 2, sizeMan = 3)
```

No matter what I change, I end up with an unreadable plot. Can I do some "Stacking" or "dodging", or maybe a hierarchical, tree-like structure?

Also, why is it so low quality? Can I change resolution?

[image]